# Convert hadoop's Configuration to Map<String, String>

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

How can I convert hadoop's `Configuration conf` to `Map<String, String>`?

I have a method that takes Map as an argument and I want to pass Configuration conf to it, so how to convert between the two ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Iterator provided by the [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#iterator%28%29) and build the Map.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator = configuration.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
  map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

You can also take a look [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#getValByRegex%28java.lang.String%29) method, which take a regex and returns a Map<> of configuration.

Comment: You can also do `for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : configuration) { map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); }`

Answer (score 1):

why not do something like:

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(String key: conf.getKeys()){
    config.put(key, conf.getString(key));
}
```

That is, iterate over all the entries and add to `Map`.